# XML comments are not shown in Swagger documentation, is this bug in swagger?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-2.0

The Swagger xml comments are not showing in the doc UI, not sure i am missing something here.. atleast someone direct me that this is a bug

> **Step1: Create a new brand new ASP.NET web application Web API project**

[image]

> **Step2: Created a Web API Project**

[image]

> **Step3: Installed Swashbuckle 5.6.0 NuGet packages**

[image]

> **Step4: Enabled to generate XML documentation file (Project properties
> -> Build)**

[image]

> **Step5: Updated SwaggerConfig.cs to includeXmlComments**

```
public static void Register()
{
    var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
                var xmlFile = "bin\\" + $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
     });
}
```

> **Step6: Added XML comments to the controller**

```
///<Summary>
/// Get these comments1
///</Summary>
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    ///<Summary>
    /// Get these comments2
    ///</Summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The WebApplication1.xml is generated in the bin folder too

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>WebApplication1</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController">
            <Summary>
             Get these comments1
            </Summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Get">
            <Summary>
             Get these comments2
            </Summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Get(System.Int32)">
            <Summary>
             Get these comments3
            </Summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Post(System.String)">
            <Summary>
             Get these comments4
            </Summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Put(System.Int32,System.String)">
            <Summary>
             Get these comments5
            </Summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Delete(System.Int32)">
            <Summary>
             Get these comments6
            </Summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

But the Swagger UI not showing comments, I am not sure where i am getting wrong here:
[image]

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the xmlPath variable and check if the path is correct

Comment: The XML path is correct and i do see the XML file with comments created in the bin folder

Comment: on the first step you are creating ASP.NET Core project, but SwaggerConfig.cs is created when you add Swashbuckle package to ASP.NET Web API. If you are using Core, use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package

Comment: @YegorAndrosov did you find the solution?

Comment: @GuilhermeWaltricke OP's issue was because of they were using ASP.NET package instead of Core

Comment: In my case I have .net framework 4.5.2 and added Swashbuckle.Core.Net45 and voila!

Comment: The experience in my before comment wa only luck ,the true cause was I had using MetaData Classes and Swagger get the summary of whose classes for the documentation.  Excuse me!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For .NET 6 make sure you configure your `program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, 
  $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
});
```

Then add the property group in your .csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: very good, thanks

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the XML comments were missing in Swagger because the API itself and the model classes are in different assemblies.

I solved it like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        // ...other stuff

        // include API xml documentation
        var apiAssembly = typeof(SomeApiClass).Assembly;
        c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlDocumentationFileFor(apiAssembly));

        // include models xml documentation
        var modelsAssembly = typeof(ModelsProject.SomeModelClass).Assembly;
        c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlDocumentationFileFor(modelsAssembly));
    });
}

private static string GetXmlDocumentationFileFor(Assembly assembly)
{
    var documentationFile = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.xml";
    var path = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, documentationFile);

    return path;
}
```

Of course, don't forget to enable XML documentation in both `.csproj` files as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

1. remove old
2. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select Edit `<project_name>.csproj`.
3. Manually add the highlighted lines to the `.csproj` file

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

4. generate new file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/aspnet/aspnetcore.docs/getstarted-swashbuckle-aspnetcore/?tabs=visual-studio

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 6 another way of doing it base on this [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments):

Opening Project file .csproj and add this lines

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then in Program file Change this:

```
  builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

To this

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // using System.Reflection;
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the comments weren't appearing because I had put a url inside the remarks. Not sure why it broke it, but once I had removed the url everything worked.

Comment: You provided the hint I needed.  In my case, I included an ampersand inside the remarks, i.e. <remarks>... & ...</remarks> and all my diligent documentation became invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include any ampersands in your remarks.  If you do, you documentation will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

At my case, I set always copy for xml generated at build option.

and at startup at AddSwaggerGen option, I add the some code, if file exist, generate comments by IncludeXmlComments :

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen((opt) =>
        {
            opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1",
                Description = "Your app desc",
                Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Name = "@yourname",
                    Url = new System.Uri("yoursite.com"),
                }
            });

            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

            if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
                opt.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue for getting XML comments for controllers in the swagger page UI in .net6 core. I found a simple solution by enabling the "XML Documentation file path" option in the properties of the project. you can follow below mentioned simple steps:

- Add the functionality while configuring thr swagger in program.cs or startup.cs

  builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen
  (c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
  {
  Title = "JWTToken_Auth_API",
  Version = "v1"
  });
  c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
  });
- Right-click on the project and open the properties.
- Go to Build -> Output -> Enable "Documentation file".
  (Also, you can set your path for XML documentation file or the default location will be used)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXSc5.png)